# Facebook API manage_groups permission to create a group

Tags: facebook, facebook-group

I want to create and manage a group through the Facebook API. There are some older messages here (more than a year old) that say it can't be done -- is that still the case? Has anyone managed to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to mark groups' statuses as 'read' (so the unread count in the groups json via the Graph API goes down to 0).  From what I can tell, to do anything with groups, you need a **manage_groups** permission, however using their OAuth for the Graph API, and trying to include the manage_groups permission returns an error suggestion the permission does not exist.  Looks like a catch-22 for now.

Please consider subscribing to this facebook bug to help move it along faster:
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/251651251563163

Answer (score 0):

It looks like *user_groups* is the permission your looking for.

Answer (score 0):

- Any valid access token if the group is public (i.e. the group's privacy setting is OPEN)
- "user_groups" permission to retrieve any groups that the session user is a member of.
- The "user_managed_groups" permission can be used to read the group content for a group in which the user is an admin. This permission also allows the app to post as the user in the group if the app is also granted the "publish_actions" permission. An app granted this permission can continue to use these capabilities even if the user stops being an admin of the group, although the user can remove the app from the group manually.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/group